# print chess field while program is running

Tags: python, chess

I'm using the chess library with Python to print a chess field. My problem is that I can't print the chess field while the program is running. I use Jupiter Notebook and if I just have a short code I can print the chess board with *"chess.Board()"* but if I have a code with 100 lines where I want to print the field while the program is running the program isn't printing the chess field at all. I want to print the chess field while the program is running and not after it is finished.

If I use `print(chess.Board())` I get:

```
r n b q k b n r
p p p p p p p p
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
P P P P P P P P
R N B Q K B N R
```

instead of the real image I get with "board".

working code:

```
import chess

chess.Board()
```

[output for working chess field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7YNY.png)

not working:

```
import chess
import time

time.sleep(5)
chess.Board()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You've been spoiled by Jupyter's automatic printing of things.  Use `print(chess.Board())`.

Comment: Then it is printing "r n b q k b n r
p p p p p p p p
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
P P P P P P P P
R N B Q K B N R" instead of the real picture of the chess field. If i just have board it prints the real image and not the asc2 of it.

Comment: Yes, because Jupyter does special handling for interactive execution, but it isn't interfering when scripts are run at speed.  You can try calling `chess.svg.board()` directly, but I suspect you'll need to integrate graphics handling into your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SVG and display.

```
import time

import chess.svg
from IPython.display import SVG, display


print('sleeping for 5s')
time.sleep(5)

b = chess.Board()
svg = chess.svg.board(b, size=250)
display(SVG(data=svg))

print('again sleeping for 5s')
time.sleep(5)
print('done')
```

#### Output

[image]